# SnapShot isn't working for pages, but is for JavaScript? [LR 11.52]

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

My company is using LoadRunner 11.52 I'm currently doing some scripting but unfortunately I'm not able to use Page View using SnapShot but can with HTML View. It is worth noting it also works for JavaScript but not the actual page that was generated.

It has the hourglass icon on the mouse appearing but  nothing seems to happen after that, I've checked for any potential pop ups asking to authenticate my credentials, however nothing is happening. Has anyone else had this problem at all, and is there any fixes that may be used?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The PageView renders the page as it was rendered by the **LoadRunner internal browser** and not how it was rendered by the recorded browser. The internal browser is optimized for speed and memory footprint and therefore (and this is intentional) doesn't have all the functionality of your other browsers. The PageView is just an attempt to help you see something rendered, it doesn't always work and you shouldn't rely on it for HTTP protocol.

If you have a problem with a specific script you can open a case with HP LoadRunner support and send them the script for investigation or use the official LoadRunner Support Forum (Google it) for help.

Comment: Hi Buzzy, thanks for the response. Sorry I didn't explain myself properly (as normal!) when I press Page View it appears for a split second then disappears for some reason.

Comment: Then you can either open a case with the support or start a new thread on the LoadRunner Support Forum. Attach the script and someone from HP dev will check it. Also you can try with the latest LR version (12.01). If none of the above works then comment here.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason your snapshot isn't rendering in pageview mode. You can always open the snapshot manually.

In your script code look for the snapshot number "Snapshot=t123.inf", go to your script folder and data subfolder. Then open the response body for that snapshot in your browser.